# Designing Data Structure (DB) allowing duplicate datas

Tags: c, database, data-structures

I'm googling for a while and quite surprised to know it is hard to find DS I want.

actions are simple : 
'i' for insert, 'd' for delete, 's' for search in Data Structure.

For ex : 
i 3 / 
i 5 /
d 3 /
i 5 /
s 4 /

...

DB must be able to save duplicate datas and when deletion(of duplicate) is made, random data will be deleted.
Insertion is NOT overlapping but just adding.

For ex. If I implement with array,

1 2 3 3 4 5 4:

If I want to 'i 3', 3 can be inserted in anywhere. Doesn't matter the order.

If I want to 'd 4', 4 can be deleted randomly and doesn't matter if result become: 1 2 3 3 5 4, or 1 2 3 3 4 5

If I want to 's 1', it is enough to tell me if element exist or not. It doesn't have to tell me the index. In this case, it will show 'yes'.

I built a RedBlack Binary Tree and I knew in RB tree, no duplicate data insertion are allowed.
Array and Lists seems it's performance is quite low. And Normal Tree as many people know, it can be unbalanced.

What are good DS that can save/delete/search duplicate datas, too?
I'm considering Hash Table but as least I understand, when duplicate data is inputted, old one is replaced to new one :(

And language is C.

Comment: You have not described exactly what should happen when there are duplicate insertions and what should be the result if a search is done on a value that has had duplicate insertions.

Comment: @kaylum Yes I added some description. Thanks for telling

Comment: With a hash table, you would likely already have a linked list at each bucket/bin to deal with collisions.  As the programmer, you can decide to allow duplicate identical keys in that list.

Comment: That still isn't very precise. Are those **keys** or actual **data**? If they are actual  data then there is no need to create seperate nodes for duplicate data. Just have a count for each node.

Comment: @kaylum 
It is actual data. To confess, I'm still confused with using a word 'key' or 'data'.

Comment: Well, if it is data then there is no point storing `3,3,3,3,3` for example. Just store a single node `{val=3, count=5}`. Then can use any standard data structure by modifying the insert to create or increment a node and the delete to decrement or remove a node.

Comment: @kaylum Wow. That's brilliant idea kaylum! Pair of val and count! I guess I should create DS with nodes, each saving pair of val and count! What kind of DS will fit to save pair of datas? I first thought of RB tree but tree has 1 data(or key) isn't it?